# WSO2 Identity Server not able to see SAML SSO option under Manage

Tags: wso2

I installed WSO2 Identity server and logged in using admin/admin, but under home pane, I am not able to see SAML SSO, OAuth entries under Manage category. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to login as "admin", to create a new role and validate the list of permission settings visible under this role (see icon permissions). A tree with checkboxes should be visible defining the permission level for each role, by this defining the permissions inherited to the account. Once the role is defined, create and add a user account to this role. Logout and login with the new administrator userid and hopefully you will see all options on the menu.

Comment: No haven't tried this, thanks, hope this will resolve the issue. Thanks :-)